# calculating distance showing wrong some time with latitude and longitude

Tags: android

I have calculated the distance between two places by using Latitude and longitude.Some times it showing wrong distance.I need to calculate exact distance in miles. Could you please help. what should i make changes in my code.
Here is my Code. 
lat2 and lng2 are the current location geo points I have taken these by NETWORK PROVIDER/GPS.
lat1 and lng2 are the destination geo poin

```
                   double earthRadius = 3958.75;//earthRadius in miles
               // double earthRadius = 6371;
                double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat1-lat2);
                double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng1-lng2);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                           Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) *
                           Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
                double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                double dist = earthRadius * c;//distance in miles
```

Thanks you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
 float results[] = new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(latitude_a, longitude_a, latitude_b,longitude_b, results);
    distance = results[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
       return (dist);
    }

   private double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
   private double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```